# Programmatically input angularjs text field using javascript/VBA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vba, excel

I am web scraping from AngularJS application using Excel VBA. I am trying to enter value in text-input by using something like- `ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")(15).Value = "112233"`
 I also tried- `ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementsByTagName('button')[15].Value = '112233';`

None of them is working. I have search few other posted questions but problems still exists. The element is:

```
<input whole-number="" type="text" maxlength="20" class="......" ng-model="pList.pNumber" bs-typeahead="typeahead_ProjectNumber"  placeholder="enter a value" data-provide="typeahead" ng-change="reduceScrollMax()">
```

Comment: even tried 'angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[15]).scope().title = "112233"';      followed by 'scope().apply();'

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution to the problem:

```
angular.element(document.getElementByTagName('input')[15]).scope().pList.pNumber = '112233';
```

followed by
    `angular.element(document.getElementByTagName('input')[15]).scope().$apply();` 
OR `angular.element(document.getElementByTagName('input')[15]).scope().$digest();`

Include the above mentioned in `ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "..."` to run it using VBA.